# Observable.Retry that logs a message?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observable

I have this Observable:

```
var obs = Observable
                .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(asyncFunc))
                .Retry()
```

It works, but I would like know when the sequence retries, so I would like to invoke a `Logger.Log("Retrying...")` whenever this happens.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply put some bog standard logging operator around it.

This does more than what you want but "teach a man to fish" - https://github.com/LeeCampbell/RxCookbook/blob/master/Instrumentation/Logging.md

```
Observable.Create<Unit>(obs =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Subscribing!!");
    return Observable.FromAsync(AsyncFunc).Subscribe(obs);
}).Retry();
```

Comment: Could it be modified so that logging happens only on retries, exluding the initial subscription?